# Rename-Item with SubString/lastIndexOf

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rename about 500 files in a single directory. Each file is .docx format similar to the below.

```
Apartment_7-9_01_92.docx
Apartment_7-9_02_192.docx
```

etc.

I want to remove the last two/three digits before the '.', including the '_' so that I end up with

```
Apartment_7-9_01.docx
Apartment_7-9_02.docx
```

Having never really used Powershell, the research I've done so far leads me to something like the below:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName -Replace $_.Name.SubString(0, $_.lastIndexOf('_')),".docx"}
```

I would have thought this would take everything, including and after the last '_' and replace it with '.docx', but it's telling me the lastIndexOf method doesn't exist in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first split the `BaseName` on `"_"`, then take every item except the last and rejoin back on `"_"`. An easy way to do that is with `$array[0..($array.Length - 2)]`. You could also just do `$array[0..2]` to take the first 3 items. You can then add the `Extension` at the end. From here you can simply rename the `FullName` with `Rename-Item`.

```
$Path = "PATH/TO/FILES"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File | ForEach-Object {
    $items = $_.BaseName -split "_"
    $newFileName = ($items[0..($items.Length - 2)] -join "_") + $_.Extension
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newFileName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your code, but I don't think it does what you want.  $_ is a fileinfo object, and $_.name is a string, and .lastindexof() is a string method.  I think you want to replace a substring location after the last "_", not before it.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName (
$_.name -Replace $_.Name.SubString(0, $_.Name.lastIndexOf('_')),".docx") -whatif}

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
 /Users/js/Apartment_7-9_01_92.docx Destination: /Users/js/.docx_92.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
 /Users/js/Apartment_7-9_02_192.docx Destination: /Users/js/.docx_192.docx".
```

This seems to work, and is close to what you were trying.  Just specify where the substring starts.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName (
$_.name -Replace $_.Name.SubString($_.Name.lastIndexOf('_')),".docx") -whatif}

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
 /Users/js/Apartment_7-9_01_92.docx Destination:
 /Users/js/Apartment_7-9_01.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
 /Users/js/Apartment_7-9_02_192.docx Destination:
 /Users/js/Apartment_7-9_02.docx".
```

There's a way to pipe directly to rename-item too, like in the docs:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName {
$_.name -Replace $_.Name.SubString($_.Name.lastIndexOf('_')),".docx"} -whatif
```